# Why is Autofit Labeling greyed out?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2007

I Have created a bar chart in a 2007 .xls file, but the data labels cannot be resized. When you go to the "format Data Labels" and then click on alignment, the Autofit and Internal Margin option is grayed out. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

**Short version:**  It is greyed out for chart text, because it the option doesn’t apply.

**Long version:** 
This is because on a chart, chart text do need to use margins, rather you can you can just move the text., and set its X and Y position. For example take the Chart Title, if you want more space to the left, just click and drag the title to the right. If you want the chart title to be bigger you just set a larger font, you have complete control over the title, as well as all other text on that chart, axis titles, legends, data labels, etc.

Internal margins are meant to be used when you don’t have complete control take for example text in a shape. If you insert a shape in your workbook, and add text to it, you cannot just pick the text up and move it to the right if you want more space on the left, so you can set the margin.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick that worked for me:

My problem was: I added more text to the axis title and it was too long for it's original shape so some text went into second line.

My solution: I type the complete text somewhere else, copy the text, double click on the axis title and delete the original text -- the cursor would still be there -- now insert the copied text. Done! They are all in one line!

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution to resize label to a single line: Data labels in a chart will often wrap themselves, when you dont want them to.  They would often seem better in a vertical single line above the graph item.  Reset them to one single line by editing the text in the label, deleting the Excel imposed return, and replace it with a space.  The line, and label box, will resize to fit a single line.  However because you have "manually interfered with the lable, it will no longer update for changing graph data.  You would have to double click each lable then reset it.  Most annoying.

Answer (score 0):

A way around it is to make the chart area big. The data label boxes will resize to fit the words in one line. Then make the chart small (not the chart area).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Manually insert a textbox into the bar chart and type in the label that way. It's annoying and labor-intensive, but it works.